# C++: Every time, the function is returning empty vector. Why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, stl

I have been trying to solve this problem:

> Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such
> that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have ***exactly*** one solution,
> and you may not use the same element twice.

**Example:**

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, 
return [0, 1].
```

I have been trying to solve this using `map` and *my attempted solution* is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    std::map<int, int> indices;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        auto it = indices.find(target - nums[i]);

        if (it != indices.end())
            return {it->first, i};

        indices[i] = nums[i];
    }
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums = {2, 7, 11, 15};
    int target = 9;

    std::vector<int> ans = twoSum(nums, target);

    for(const auto &elem : ans) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To avoid two for loops, I'm trying to find `target - num2` because num1 + num2 = target.

So, the logic is to

- create a map from the input vector `nums`
- use `map.find(target - num[i])`
- return the first value of iterator pointing to `target-nums[i]`, i.e., the `key` for the `value` = target-nums[i], in the map and `i`.

Therefore, for the above code, the function should return `{0, 1}`

However, every time, I get an empty vector. Could anyone please tell me whether my logic is wrong or I'm manipulating the map or vector wrongly?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger?  Or adding more cout statements to show what the values are as it runs?  This is basic troubleshooting process you need to learn if you want to program anything non-trivial.  If you can identify a specific line where it doesn't do what you want, and you don't understand why, then fair enough to ask here.

Comment: When you do `indices.find(target - nums[i])`, you assume the key is the number and the value is the index. But when you do `indices[i] = nums[i]`, you assume the opposite. Figure out which way you want to go, and be consistent.

Comment: Oh yes, you are absolutely right @Igor Tandetnik. Thank you so much. I think I have to understand `map.find()` even better.

Comment: @Paul Sanders, but how can I preserve/get two indices using a `set`?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to solving the problem but your code has a small yet critical issue.

You add elements to your map as **(key=index, value=number)**

```
indices[i] = nums[i];
```

... Essentially, you just recreated the array in a different format, so if you think about it, for every `i`, `nums[i] == indices[i]`. This approach really doesn't get you any further in solving your problem.

Instead, you should try mapping **(key=number, value=index)**

```
indices[nums[i]] = i;
```

This way, when you search the map for a previously-encountered number as you already are

```
auto it = indices.find(target - nums[i]);
```

... You end up searching for the number itself instead of an index!

Note that you will also need to change the return to use the **index** instead of the **value**, as the format of your map is now different

```
auto it = indices.find(target - nums[i]);
if (it != indices.end())
    return {it->second, i};
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing: `indices[num[i]] = 1`.

You are using the index as the key of the map, but you should really be using the values.

Comment: did you mean `indices[num[i]] = i` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a map at all.

```
std::vector<int> twoSum(const std::vector<int> & nums, int target) {
    for (int it1 = nums.begin(); it1 != nums.end(); ++it1) {
        auto it2 = std::find(std::next(it1), nums.end(), target - *it1);

        if (it2 != nums.end())
            return {std::distance(nums.begin(), it1), std::distance(nums.begin(), it2)};
    }

    // You can assume this is never reached, throwing is noisier than returning empty
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid arguments to twoSum");
}
```